# Local wordpress setup with SPAM in the incoming links dashboard section?

Tags: dashboard, spam

I am developing a website on my localhost and i just notice a bunch of incoming links in the dashboard's incoming links section, which doesn't look valid.

When i visit the urls i don't see a reffer to my localhost/domain.com.

the only plugin i had active was "Regenerate Thumbnails". I disabled the plugin but i can still see the links.

How can i fix this?

regards

Comment: its something that you shouldn't worried about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The incoming links widget is asking Google for links to the domain you’re on right now. If your domain is `localhost` you get a lot of links – because that’s a very common domain name. Unfortunately, some people don’t clean up their data when they move from localhost to the world wide web, and then Google will find these links. :)

Nothing to worry about.

Comment: tx what do you do if you were making a theme for a client? edit the google search url or just hide it? curious

Comment: @alex You set up a custom local domain, for example `client.dev`. No back links. :)